# Changing all occurrences in a folder

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I need to do a regex find and replace on all the files in a folder (and its subfolders). What would be the linux shell command to do that?

For example, I want to run this over all the files and overwrite the old file with the new, replaced text.

```
sed 's/old text/new text/g'
```

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/find-and-replace-string-in-all-files.html

Answer (score 212, accepted):

There is no way to do it using only sed. You'll need to use at least the find utility together:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak "s/foo/bar/g" {} \;
```

This command will create a `.bak` file for each changed file.

**Notes:**

- The `-i` argument for `sed` command is a GNU extension, so, if you are running this command with the BSD's `sed` you will need to redirect the output to a new file then rename it.
- The `find` utility does not implement the `-exec` argument in old UNIX boxes, so, you will need to use a `| xargs` instead.

Comment: What is `\;` for?

Comment: We need to tell to find where the command of the argument -exec ends with a ”;”. But the shell uses the same symbol (;) as a shell command separator, so, we need to escape the ”;” from the shell to pass it to the find’s -exec argument.

Comment: It's worth noting that `-i` by itself does not create a backup file, and is what causes sed to perform the operation on the file in place.

Comment: What is `{}` for ?

Comment: The `{}` will be replaced by each filename found by `find` and `\;` tells to find that the command that he needs to execute finish at this point.

Comment: `sed -i.bak 's/REPLACE_THIS/WITH_THIS/' *` seems to work on any file in the current folder. Is this acceptable if subfolder replacements are not needed?

Comment: `sed -i.bak 's/REPLACE_THIS/WITH_THIS/g' *` (Edit to prior comment)

Answer (score 81):

I prefer to use `find | xargs cmd` over `find -exec` because it's easier to remember.

This example globally replaces "foo" with "bar" in .txt files at or below your current directory:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/foo/bar/g"
```

The `-print0` and `-0` options can be left out if your filenames do not contain funky characters such as spaces.

Comment: If you're on OSX, try `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' "s/foo/bar/g"` (note providing an empty string to the `-i` argument).

Comment: On MacOS, run `sed -i.bak` instead of `sed -i`. I think as mentioned by @JakubKukul , `sed -i ''` also works.

Answer (score 8):

For portability, I don't rely on features of sed that are specific to linux or BSD.  Instead I use the `overwrite` script from Kernighan and Pike's book on the Unix Programming Environment.

The command is then

```
find /the/folder -type f -exec overwrite '{}' sed 's/old/new/g' {} ';'
```

And the `overwrite` script (which I use all over the place) is

```
#!/bin/sh
# overwrite:  copy standard input to output after EOF
# (final version)

# set -x

case $# in
0|1)        echo 'Usage: overwrite file cmd [args]' 1>&2; exit 2
esac

file=$1; shift
new=/tmp/$$.new; old=/tmp/$$.old
trap 'rm -f $new; exit 1' 1 2 15    # clean up files

if "$@" >$new               # collect input
then
    cp $file $old   # save original file
    trap 'trap "" 1 2 15; cp $old $file     # ignore signals
          rm -f $new $old; exit 1' 1 2 15   # during restore
    cp $new $file
else
    echo "overwrite: $1 failed, $file unchanged" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
rm -f $new $old
```

The idea is that it overwrites a file only if a command succeeds.  Useful in `find` and also where you would not want to use

```
sed 's/old/new/g' file > file  # THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK
```

because the shell truncates the file before `sed` can read it.

Answer (score 8):

Example: inline replace {AutoStart} with 1 for all of the ini files under the /app/config/ folder and its child folders:

```
sed -i 's/{AutoStart}/1/g' /app/config/**/*.ini
```

Comment: This doesn't replace it, it just prints out the replacement - if you want to replace it, add the inline flag: `sed -i 's/{AutoStart}/1/g' /app/config/**/*.ini`

Answer (score 3):

Might I suggest (after backing up your files):

```
find /the/folder -type f -exec sed -ibak 's/old/new/g' {} ';'
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (on mac terminal, on Linux you don't need `'' -e`):

```
sed -i '' -e 's/old text/new text/g' `grep 'old text' -rl *`
```

the command `grep 'old text' -rl *` lists all files in the working directory (and subdirectories) where "old text" exists. This then is passed in sed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about clobbering files that you accidentally haven't considered, you can run `grep` with the recursive option first to see which files will be potentially changed:

```
grep -r 'searchstring' *
```

It's then not hard to put together something that will run the replacement on each of these files:

```
for f in $(grep -r 'searchstring' *)
do
    sed -i -e 's/searchstring/replacement/g' "$f"
done
```

(Only valid with *GNU sed* - adjustments would be needed for POSIX compatibility as the `-i` inplace option is a GNU extension):

Answer (score -1):

Might want to try [my mass search/replace Perl script](http://lostsouls.org/grimoire_convert_all).  Has some advantages over chained-utility solutions (like not having to deal with multiple levels of shell metacharacter interpretation).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Fcntl qw( :DEFAULT :flock :seek );
use File::Spec;
use IO::Handle;

die "Usage: $0 startdir search replace\n"
    unless scalar @ARGV == 3;
my $startdir = shift @ARGV || '.';
my $search = shift @ARGV or
    die "Search parameter cannot be empty.\n";
my $replace = shift @ARGV;
$search = qr/\Q$search\E/o;

my @stack;

sub process_file($) {
    my $file = shift;
    my $fh = new IO::Handle;
    sysopen $fh, $file, O_RDONLY or
        die "Cannot read $file: $!\n";
    my $found;
    while(my $line = <$fh>) {
        if($line =~ /$search/) {
            $found = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
    if($found) {
        print "  Processing in $file\n";
        seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;
        my @file = <$fh>;
        foreach my $line (@file) {
            $line =~ s/$search/$replace/g;
        }
        close $fh;
        sysopen $fh, $file, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC or
            die "Cannot write $file: $!\n";
        print $fh @file;
    }
    close $fh;
}

sub process_dir($) {
    my $dir = shift;
    my $dh = new IO::Handle;
    print "Entering $dir\n";
    opendir $dh, $dir or
        die "Cannot open $dir: $!\n";
    while(defined(my $cont = readdir($dh))) {
        next
            if $cont eq '.' || $cont eq '..';
        # Skip .swap files
        next
            if $cont =~ /^\.swap\./o;
        my $fullpath = File::Spec->catfile($dir, $cont);
        if($cont =~ /$search/) {
            my $newcont = $cont;
            $newcont =~ s/$search/$replace/g;
            print "  Renaming $cont to $newcont\n";
            rename $fullpath, File::Spec->catfile($dir, $newcont);
            $cont = $newcont;
            $fullpath = File::Spec->catfile($dir, $cont);
        }
        if(-l $fullpath) {
            my $link = readlink($fullpath);
            if($link =~ /$search/) {
                my $newlink = $link;
                $newlink =~ s/$search/$replace/g;
                print "  Relinking $cont from $link to $newlink\n";
                unlink $fullpath;
                my $res = symlink($newlink, $fullpath);
                warn "Symlink of $newlink to $fullpath failed\n"
                    unless $res;
            }
        }
        next
            unless -r $fullpath && -w $fullpath;
        if(-d $fullpath) {
            push @stack, $fullpath;
        } elsif(-f $fullpath) {
            process_file($fullpath);
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}

if(-f $startdir) {
    process_file($startdir);
} elsif(-d $startdir) {
    @stack = ($startdir);
    while(scalar(@stack)) {
        process_dir(shift(@stack));
    }
} else {
    die "$startdir is not a file or directory\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in $(ls);do sed -i 's/old_text/new_text/g' $i;done
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it's better to include an explanation on how your code addresses the OP's issue. This way, future visitors can learn from your post, & apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, complete answers reinforce this idea, and are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts be self-contained, are some strengths of SO as a platform that differentiates us from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: this wont resolve the issue because it only list current working directory and does not list sub folders

Answer (score -2):

In case the name of files in folder has some regular names (like file1, file2...) I have used for cycle.

```
for i in {1..10000..100}; do sed 'old\new\g' 'file'$i.xml > 'cfile'$i.xml; done
```

Comment: this is not related to the question asked. The question does not mention anything about same file / folder name pattern. Please avoid such answers